# Permission to see hidden fields

Tags: users

There is a node type with hidden fields. Anyone can find nodes of that content type from the search form, and see open information. To see all the fields, users must make a request to the node owner, who decides the users who can see, or not those fields.

Is there any module with this purpose? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with the field permissions module. You can then specify that users without permission cannot view the field.

Secondly, create a new user role for the people who can see the field. When a user makes a request to see the field, you can set the field permission to view the field by assigning the new role to that user.